# CAML query on people and group

Tags: caml

I have a list with a "People and Groups" type column and multiple selection allowed is checked. Another column call "Region"

Say, I have John, doe and barry, williams in the "SalesGuy" column and Region is SW.

How do I do a CAML query where only want to pass 1 user john, doe or barry, williams and get the region back?

Comment: Is there a relationship established between the lists like a lookup column?

Comment: No relation. Plain list with 2 columns. SalesPeople and Region. SalesPeople column is populated with bunch of users.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread the question.

Answer (score 2):

Contains is not exact - what happens if you have multiple Williams?

```
        <Where>
           <Includes>
              <FieldRef Name='Initiators' LookupId='TRUE'/>
              <Value Type='Integer'>7</Value>
           </Includes>
        </Where>
```

Where **7** is the ID of the SPUser of Williams.

Answer (score -1):

The answers is Contains. Also, if i put williams, berry it works.

```
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name="Initiators" />
            <Value Type="UserMulti">williams</Value>
        </Contains>
```

Comment: But what if there are two users named "williams, berry" and "williams, berrys"? You should always use the ID from the User Information List.